# Can you save your history from Jupyter Console as either .py or .ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm still pretty new to Python so I experiment with code a lot in the iPython console in JupyterLab before I put the code in my actual notebook/script.

Every so often though, I end up having some valuable stuff in my history and want to save my history of commands (because if I understand correctly, once I close that console it's gone forever).

Is there a way to save that history without executing `%hist` and then copying and pasting?

I can't see anything in the JupyterLab menu:

[image]

Comment: What you can do on `ipython` console, you can do in cells of a Jupyter notebook. On the notebook, you can use `%hist` to list the commands too. But it's a redundant, because what you run (cell by cell) are there already (In[i], Out[j]). Remember that, Jupyter notebook is super-ipython.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I've been trying this and it's better. I'm used to RStudio where I'd have a script that slowly gets added to depending on what works in the console and what doesn't, but the Jupyter Notebook workflow is a bit different. I'll learn eventually :P